# Google Cloud FunctionsからGoogle Spread Sheetに書き込みをしたい。

Tags: python, google-cloud, google-spreadsheet, google-api

まず、目的はPythonを使って、Cloud Functionsで関数を定期的に動かしてGoogle Spread Sheetに書き込むことです。

Cloud Functionsに書いた関数は下に置きます。
以下のサイトを参考に、ローカル環境から目的のGoogle Spread Sheetに書き込みをしていくことには成功しました。

[PythonでGoogleスプレッドシートに書き込みする方法](https://www.teijitaisya.com/python-gsheets/)

また、Cloud Functionsにおいてデプロイには成功、しかし関数のテストをするとエラーが出ました。

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Details:
500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

ログの「エラー」を見ると、スプレッドシートのjson秘密鍵がない、と言われているようです。

```
line 79, in from_filename with io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as json_file: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'json秘密鍵ファイルのパス.json'
```

ローカルでは処理に成功してCloud Functionsではエラーになるのは、Cloud Functionsからはローカルのファイルにアクセスできないからだと思うのですが、この場合Cloud Functionsで動かしている関数がjson秘密鍵ファイルを使えるようにする（もしくは他の方法でCloud Functionsで動かしている関数がスプレッドシートに書き込めるようになる）にはどうしたらよいのでしょうか？

初心者なので見当違いな質問かもしれないのですが、教えていただけると大変助かります。よろしくお願いします。

---

main.py

```
import datetime
import gspread
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from apiclient.discovery import build

def main():

    #スプレッドシートIDを変数に格納する。
    SPREADSHEET_KEY = 'シートID' #シートID
    #ダウンロードしたjsonファイル名をクレデンシャル変数に設定。
    WHEREFILE = "json秘密鍵ファイルのローカルでのパス"
    #json秘密鍵ファイルのパス
    
    data = dataを持ってくる関数
    WriteVC(SPREADSHEET_KEY,WHEREFILE,data)
    return 0

def dataを持ってくる関数

def WriteVC(SPREADSHEET_KEY,WHEREFILE,data):
    # お決まりの文句
    # 2つのAPIを記述しないとリフレッシュトークンを3600秒毎に発行し続けなければならない
    scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

    #ダウンロードしたjsonファイル名をクレデンシャル変数に設定。
    credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(WHEREFILE,scopes=scope)
    
    #OAuth2の資格情報を使用してGoogle APIにログイン。
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

    # スプレッドシート（ブック）を開く
    workbook = gc.open_by_key(SPREADSHEET_KEY)

    # シートの一覧を取得する。（リスト形式）
    worksheet = workbook.worksheets()

        # シートを開く
    worksheet = workbook.worksheet('シート1')

    nextcell = worksheet.find('next')
    nextrow = nextcell.row             # 次の値を入れる行番号

    tnow = datetime.datetime.now()

        # next行にタイムスタンプとデータを書き込み。

    strtnow = tnow.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    worksheet.update_cell(nextrow, 1, strtnow)
    worksheet.update_cell(nextrow, 2, data)
    worksheet.update_cell(nextrow+1, 1, 'next')
    
    print(tnow)
```

requirements.txt

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
gspread>=5.4.0
google-api-python-client>=2.52.0
google-auth-httplib2>=0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib>= 0.5.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
google cloud functionsのコード部分に、main.pyの下にcredential.jsonを作ってjson秘密鍵を書き込めばテストに成功しました。